# House Has Different Types of Siding - How to look seamless?

Tags: brick, siding, vinyl-siding

Alright, I am looking to purchase my first house. One of which looks somewhat like the one below. As you can see, it has a brick sided portion and a vinyl sided portion. Obviously this house has been added onto, like the one I am looking at. Is there a way that this house can be made to look seamless so it all looks original? I wouldn't miss brick but do like stone. Also, being that it has been added onto, is there anything I should look for?

[image]

Comment: If there is brick under that horrible vinyl. rip it off. If not then put vinyl(with insulation) around the rest of the house. Congratulations on buying a new place.. its.. Awesome!

Comment: Not necessarily applicable to your house, but some trivia: some new housing developments mandate 'x square feet of brick' on front of house. This leads to ridiculous looking McMansions with one wall of solid brick, and 4 walls of the cheapest vinyl siding. ;)

Answer (score 3):

It's mostly aesthetics, so opinions may vary.

I don't what your budget is, but I see many ways it could be improved:

- The white siding part could be changed to match the beige siding to the right, or if the foundation allows it, replace the white siding with the same brick as the rest.
- The white door could be painted (or changed altogether) to match the main door.
- If the door in the white siding section is not used (there is no porch, so I guess it isn't), maybe you could remove it and center the window (or change it for a larger window).
- If the door cannot be removed, can it be centered in the siding section? it would help to make it look seamless (and add a proper porch).